# vPopulate textbox field with selection from dropdown list on Web

Tags: php

Hi I am trying to display my address field when I select my authority code but the address field does not appear nor does the text is filled. My knowledge is pretty limited as I just started learning not long ago.

Main page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
  .hide{
    display: none;
  }
  .show{
    display: block;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
  <select name="auth" id="auth">
    <option value = "">Select</option>
    <?php

$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "null", "null", "null");
$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT AuthorityId FROM AuthorityList");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($authorityid);

while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<option value = '$authorityid'>$authorityid</option>";

}    
$stmt->close();
$connection->close();
?>

  </select>
</div>
</div>
<div id="address" class="hide">
  <label>Address</label>
  <textarea id='add_text' name="address"></textarea>
</div>
 </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#auth').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'getData.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:{
        val: $('#auth').val()
      },
      success:function(result){
          console.log(result);
          if(result != ''){
            $('#add_text').html(result);
            $('#address').removeClass('hide');
            $('#address').addClass('show');
          } else {
            $('#add_text').html('');
            $('#address').removeClass('show');
            $('#address').addClass('hide');
          }

      }
    })
  });
});
```

getData.php

```
<?php

$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "null", "null", "null");

$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT Address FROM AuthorityList WHERE AuthorityId = '$authorityid'");

$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($address);
$stmt ->fetch();
    if($stmt -> num_rows != 0){
    echo "<br><br> $address";
    }

//echo "$address";
$stmt->close();
$connection->close();

?>
```

Comment: recommended to use ajax, to display address on  changing 'authorityid' selectbox

Comment: above $.ajax write console.log($('#auth').val()); , check auth value get or not. we are show step by step response. ok.

Comment: @SujalPatel  
Nope auth value is not getting, console bar still shows nothing

Comment: show getData.php file new edits

Comment: @SujalPatel tried adding the extract($_POST); but still doesn't work and console bar still shows nothing

Comment: this code is in live server?

Comment: @SujalPatel yes

Comment: can i access the code? because above posted code look perfect.

Comment: @SujalPatel yeah how would you like me to send it over to you?

Comment: only send db file i will make the script you want. db file upload in github i have downloading on github.

Comment: @SujalPatel I'm not entirely sure that I have uploaded it in github. Username is zergseir and I placed the file in the pull request

Comment: i got it. i will make script and push in same repo. in github. it's a public repo?

Comment: @SujalPatel yes it is a public repo, thanks alot!!

Comment: show you repo. in patch-1 branch upload two files

Comment: @SujalPatel thanks alot man it finally worked!!

Comment: u welcome.. pls. accept my answer. thank you

Comment: @SujalPatel hi, If i were to add one more field below address called TelephoneNo, i just have to change accordingly right? Is there anything extra that I need to add in getData.php?

Comment: try to get response in json format and set the value

Comment: show your repo. patch-2 branch replace the file

Comment: @SujalPatel alright man thanks. I have added a submit button and would like to submit the data to another table in the database. however it doesnt seem to work. If you do not mind, could you help me to take a look at patch-3 in github?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>
<style>
  .hide{
    display: none;
  }
  .show{
    display: block;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>
  <select name="auth" id="auth">
    <option value="">Select Auth</option>
    <option value="1">Auth_Code_1</option>
    <option value="2">Auth_Code_2</option>
    <option value="3">Auth_Code_3</option>
    <option value="4">Auth_Code_4</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>
<div id="address" class="hide">
  <label>Address</label>
  <textarea id='add_text' name="address"></textarea>
</div>
 </body>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#auth').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url:'getData.php',
      type:'POST',
      data:{
        val: $('#auth').val()
      },
      success:function(result){
          console.log(result);
          if(result != ''){
            $('#add_text').html(result);
            $('#address').removeClass('hide');
            $('#address').addClass('show');
          } else {
            $('#add_text').html('');
            $('#address').removeClass('show');
            $('#address').addClass('hide');
          }

      }
    })
  });
});
```

getData.php (Ajax Req. File)

```
<?php

//echo $_POST['val'];

echo "address";

?>
```

In getData.php file write query for get address into the database table and simply echo the address it's set in address textarea. try this.

Comment: Hi I have tried but the address field does not show. I merely added the php select statement codes in getData.php

Comment: In getData.php file write query for get address.

Comment: these are all the codes I put in getData.php

<?php

$connection = new mysqli("localhost", "null", "null", "null");

$stmt = $connection->prepare("SELECT Address FROM AuthorityList WHERE AuthorityId = '$authorityid'");

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($address);

$stmt ->fetch();
 
 
 if($stmt -> num_rows != 0){
 echo "$address";
 }

$stmt->close();

$connection->close();

?>

Comment: I only echoed $address though, the other codes are the connection to the database and retrieving the address data from the database

Comment: See in you console write something

Comment: Im sorry but i do not understand what that means

Comment: Is there any error in console bar? Right click on mouse > select inspect > bottom screen in second option console. click the console and then run again

Comment: console bar is totally empty

Comment: can you pls. post your both of file code. without code show i can't say anything

Comment: Hi I have made the changes in the question

Answer (score 0):

Try to solve this using jquery

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#auth').click(function () {
            if($('#auth').val() == '')
            {
                $('#address').removeClass('show');
                $('#address').addClass('hide');
            } else {
                $('#address').removeClass('hide');
                $('#address').addClass('show');
            }

        })
    })
```

```css
.hide{
        display: none;
    }
    .show{
        display: block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<label>Authorize Code</label>
<select name="auth" id="auth">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Auth_Code_1</option>
    <option value="2">Auth_Code_2</option>
    <option value="3">Auth_Code_3</option>
    <option value="4">Auth_Code_4</option>
</select>
</div>
<div id="address" class="hide">
    <label>Address</label>
    <textarea name="address"></textarea>
</div>
```

i hope it's works

Comment: Hi I would like to ask how do you get the value for address from the database? Because I see that you do not have any POST or GET

Comment: this is static data. it's just show how to hide and display the address box

Comment: I would need to retrieve the address from the database as well. Is there any way that I can incorporate the php codes into your set of codes?

Comment: try ajax and in success response add value in textarea. add this two line in success response $('#address').removeClass('show'); $('#address').addClass('hide');

Comment: wow ajax is super advanced for me. Im sorry but could you show me how the codes are like?